# How to buffer a video from online in advance like youtube in reat-native?

Tags: javascript, react-native

[image: that grey colour loading]

How to buffer/load the data in advance while playing a video from server, to reduce the loading time in react-native.

Comment: Short answer: their servers are better than yours. And even if cloud based, their configuration simply allotted more resources. Meaning their download speed is better. Thats my guess, I wondered it too.

Comment: You can however play the video in a hidden element for a certain amount of time on a different page. Maybe it "caches". And if so that part would have already been loaded when you are ready to include the video for real.     ..... But i think the short answer was better. Like can the average consumer-level hosting provider really host "Youtube". Not likely.

Comment: @GetSet thanks for your quick reply but, is there any chance we can load the data in advance with code?

Comment: I think i read "preloading" somewhere. I can't recall. Research keywords "preloading html5 video"

Comment: Its a good question, glad to help